# 24v AC common/ground

Tags: transformer, ground, short-circuit, troubleshooting

I'm trying to understand what I believe to be a basic/fundamental theory, however, I seem to be over analyzing. On many hvac units the 24v or 120v control transformer common is grounded to the unit chassis. This brings the common to ground potential and helps with troubleshooting. Wouldn't grounding the common, which it obviously doesn't, unless in the event of a short, cause unwanted voltage to continuously energize the chassis or just act as a short? Why is it that it is safe to do this and the common has no voltage? Is the voltage lost/consumed through resistive loads in the circuit, such as contactor coils? I assume there is a logical and basic explanation to this and I just need it dumbed down. Any info is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: "which it obviously doesn't" *what*???

Comment: Sorry if I didn't word it correctly.  I'm not an electrical engineer, just trying to learn basic theory.  If the transformer is powered and one side is connected to ground I would think that current would flow to ground.  When I check it with a meter there is no current on ground and the common current is equal to the "hot" side of the transformer.  Is it just the physics of electricity to return to it's source?  Thanks

Comment: There are a number of terminology issues with your question such as "no voltage". What is "no voltage"? Voltage is always measured as the difference between two points, so no voltage doesn't mean much. But you can say that two things are at the same voltage/potential which means that if you try and measure the voltage between them you get 0V. Think of voltage as distance. Always measured between two points. Saying "there is no distance" doesn't tell you anything. You always have to at least point to a location from which there is no distance from, your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  By no voltage I meant that with a volt meter the common would read 0 volts to ground (because they're tied together) however current will still exist in the wire?  I tried explaining it in my above comment too

Comment: Current can still be flowing between two points if you measure "zero volts". Not a mathematical zero volts, just so small that it reads zero on your meter. In reality, everything has resistance so you will always be able to measure some voltage if current is flowing if your equipment is sensitive enough.

Comment: Except superconductors. But nonetheless, you can measure zero and still have current flowing.

Answer (score 3):

The intent of grounding the chassis isn't to help with troubleshooting.

People are assumed to be at ground potential and/or connected to ground somehow by virtue of the inability to hover. The chassis is grounded so that if a hot wire gets loose inside and makes contact with the chassis, the current will take the easier path to ground through the low resistance metal chassis instead of through the human, who is at ground or in contact with ground, touching the chassis.

If the chassis was not grounded and a hot wire got loose inside and made contact with the chassis, now the chassis would be hot. If a person, presumed to be at ground, touched the chassis the current would go to ground through the human.

> Wouldn't grounding the common, which it obviously doesn't, unless in the event of a short, cause unwanted voltage to continuously energize the chassis or just act as a short?

Ground (or earth) is assumed to be an infinite charge sink. So if you short the hot line to ground, the hot line gets pulled down to ground instead of ground being pulled hot.

> Is the voltage lost/consumed through resistive loads in the circuit, such as contactor coils?

You could think of this as so much current flows through the resistances that all the voltage is dropped across those resistances so by the current reaches the chassis which the person is touching, there is no voltage difference between ground and the chassis with which to shock a human at ground potential or connected to ground.

Comment: it does help a little, you can stick your black meter lead on any metal to find it.

Comment: Well, I mean that's not its intention.

Answer (score 2):

grounding the common doesn't put current into the ground because current only flows in circuits. and as the transformer secondary is isolated there is no circuit through ground

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAoSRO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

by grounding the trasformer secondary they can use a transformer with only functional insulation.  With it isolated from ground reinforced insulation would be needed. Thus this link to ground saves the manufacturer money.

Comment: Thank you for the response, sometimes you need to hear something a few times and when it's worded a particular way it can click.  "Current only flows in circuits and secondary is isolated so circuit through ground".  Simple stuff, but reading this helps clear up confusion, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There will be some capacitive coupling thru the transformer, from primary to secondary.

This current needs a return path.

The current will be:

I = C * dV/dT

I = 100pF (SWAG) * (377 radian/second * 160 volt)

I = 1e-10 * 60,000 = 1e-10 * 6e+4 == 6e-6

I == 6 microAmps

==============================================

To compute that capacitance, assume the primary/secondary overlap Area is
(10 cm by 10 cm) and the Distance is 1mm. Assume the relative dielectric constant is 5 (this may be some varnish_soaked paper, or plastic)

the capacitance will be

C = Eo * Er * Area / Distance, and Eo = 8.9e-12 farad/meter

C = 8.9e-12 * 5 * (10cm * 10cm)/1mm

C = 45e-12 farad/meter * 1e-2 meter*meter/0.001meter == 450pF

which 4.5 X our initial estimate.